# VirtualBox Exit Code 1 (0x1) -- MacOS 10.13.6

Tags: virtualbox

I have been using a Windows VM on my Mac for a while now but, the last time I went to use it, it said the following:

> The virtual machine 'Windows 10' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

I have tried enabling SIP, rebooting, reinstalling, and downgrading my VirtualBox version. Is there any thing else I could do to fix this?

Thanks,

Razr

Comment: The things you tried sound like they are all on the Mac side of the VM. What have you done to troubleshoot on the Windows side? I sounds like if *could be* a Windows startup problem.

Comment: How would I go about trobuleshooting the Windows VM?